# Simulating a series of rotating vertices with various masses and coupling functions

Tags: physics, solver

I continue to run into this problem: wanting to run a complex simulation of interconnected nodes, and aside from some time looking into Rigs of Rods, I don't have any experience in this area.

In this case I'm trying to simulate a series of rotating devices. If I were trying to do CFD or using more vertices, I assume I would need to try and arrive at something for use with an ODE Solver. ...but in this case I have 7 vertices with 6 edges, all in-line; I think brute force is an option. There are various functions that are used to define how force is transmitted along this line of vertices, and at any point in the chain energy/force can applied arbitrarily based on the result of 1 or more functions for a given edge.

I'm guessing that this can't be done in a single iteration without an equation that accounted for everything.

I suppose, I'll take any input. I don't know what I don't know and I wouldn't be shocked to learn that there are some great write-ups if I knew what to search for.

Comment: What you probably do not know is Lagrangian mechanics and Euler-Lagrange equations.

Comment: I think this would be a very efficient way to solve what I'm working on. But even double pendulum is a little unwieldy... I feel like I need a plug and play library that supports 1 to n vertices out of the box. ...or, I guess when I was asking for "brute force", I was thinking in terms of just using Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: Newtonian and Lagrangian mechanics will take you to the same place. Lagrangian is just a more flexible formulation of Newtonian mechanics. Are there any external forces, or does this chain of bars and joints move without external forces acting on it?

Comment: Each edge can have 1 to n functions (although it's unlikely to go beyond 3 or 4 per edge) that control how force is transmitted between each vertex, I'm using the same mechanism to add force to the system. Right now it's built object oriented and I expected to simply run a few iterations of some newtonian calculations per frame. I'm guessing that's still a viable solution? I feel like I've seen some simplified CFD simulations that do this? ...but the first thing I built could only transmit force in one direction and I figured I'd ask if someone had an example.

Comment: So I think my problem is, I understand how Lagrangian could produce a function that, given inputs, could produce the outputs I need, and that would be amazing. ...but I'm afraid producing that function will be extremely involved. I'm also pretty certain that instead, I could do some hamfisted Newtonian equations, combine the results, and arrive at the next frame. but getting each vertex to transmit force to neighbors? That's what I'm unclear on. ...It feels like I would almost need to cache force to be transmitted if I wanted to iterate more than once for a given delta time.